# ReactJS Enzyme Jest issue Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(component)" even when wrapped inside provider getting suggestion to wrap

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, enzyme-to-snapshot, jest-enzyme

Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Component)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Component) in connect options.

```
  319 |    
> 321 |             const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}>
      |                             ^
  322 |                          <{...props}/>
  323 |                        </Provider>);
  324 |             expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a react-redux mock at the top of your test file after the imports:

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  connect: () => (ReactComponent) => ReactComponent,
}));
```